# Override profile properties in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In spring boot I have the following profile:
*application-email.yaml*

```
services:
  email:
    cron: '....'
    recipient: `...`
    other properties...
```

And in test/resources directory I have *application.yaml*, I want to include all properties from *email profile*, but for tests I want to override `recipient` property.

So I expect my *application.yaml* to look like this:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    include: email

services:
  email:
    recipient: `test-email`
```

As far as I get it, spring at first read *application.yaml* in *test/resources* and then overrides it with values from profiles. 
But I want the opposite.

How can I achieve that?

**Addition 1:** 
I think I can create profile test, define my test recipient there. But can I do it without an additional profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is indeed to create a application-test.yaml, and activate the profile test.

Why do you dont want to do this ?
It's the way recommended by spring.

Comment: My concern is I have a multi-module system. Profile `email` not used in every module, but if I move `recipient: 'test-email'` to test profile - it will be populated to all modules, even for the ones, that does not need that property

Comment: @a3dsfcv So? If the code needing the property isn't used, then the property isn't used, so what's the harm? There are lots of properties in the Spring `Environment` that are never used.

Answer (score -1):

To get all your test properties and the email properties, I'd add add these annotations:

```
    @ActiveProfiles("test")
    @PropertySource("classpath:application-email.yaml")
    public class MyWonderfulTests { ...}
```

And given that you only want to override one single property, add the following static block to the top of your test-class:

```
static {
        System.setProperty("recipient", "test-email");
     }
```

That should do the trick :)

Comment: The thing is I want to override this property for all tests given this module

Comment: Using `System.setProperty` to hard-code a property value in a Spring Boot application?? Absolute not!!! Property values should be set in property files, not hard-coded in Java.